# Automatically delete spam messages

Tags: email, email-spam

I have a problem with my hotmail account. For some reason I receive a lot of messages every day which have a link lead to 3-4 sites so that they will track who opens the link. They also have unsubscribe links which go to a similar URL but it is not actually unsubscribe me. I receive 20-30 messages every day. They go to the junk folder but I can to keep this folder clean.

What I was looking for is a way to automatically delete these messages by using some kind of filtering but they use different emails every time that they send the messages and the only way to automatically delete these messages is by checking the contents of the message and find the specific URL pattern that they use in order to track the users who actually see the messages that they send.

I tried to use the hotmail rules or the thunderbird message filters but I have not found a way to find the messages which contain a specific link inside the body of the message so that the application will automatically delete them.

Is there a tool or mail client which will allow me to filter and delete these messages?

Thanks in advance,
Aristotelis

Comment: Are the senders from the same domain ? In this case you may have an option to block the whole domain in your mail client / webmail

Comment: They use different from email, subject and contents every time. The from emails also have different domains. The only common information that I can catch is the link which leads to the unsubscribe page or the link to the details page.